# I'm getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException error after i click button for update post

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I'm trying with Laravel Framework to update a post using Laravel's collective form. But after clicking on the update button, I get the error "MethodNotAllovedHttpEkception No message". Also, when I click on the subimt button in order to update a post, the question mark symbol  appear on url for example : `Localhost:8000/edit?5` . Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Error image

[image]

Form example

[image: Form]

mainController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
//if we want to use sql syntax for queries 
use DB; 
use Image;
class MainController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
     return view('login');
    }
    function checklogin(Request $request)
    {
     $this->validate($request, [
      'email'   => 'required|email',
      'password'  => 'required|alphaNum|min:3'
     ]);

     $user_data = array(
      'email'  => $request->get('email'),
      'password' => $request->get('password')
     );

     if(Auth::attempt($user_data))
     {
      return redirect('');
     }
     else
     {
      return back()->with('error', 'Wrong Login Details');
     }

    }

    function successlogin()
    {
      $posts= Post::orderby('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(3);   
     return view('main_page')-> with('posts', $posts);

    }

    function logout()
    {
     Auth::logout();
     return redirect('');
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
       return view('create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {   
        $this -> validate($request,[
            'title' => 'required',
            'content' => 'required'

        ]);


     // Handle File Upload
        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/upload', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }









        //create new post
        $post= new Post;

        $post -> title = $request -> input('title');
        $post -> content = $request -> input('content');
        $post->file_name = $fileNameToStore;
        $post -> save();

        // Check if file is present
        if( $request->hasFile('post_thumbnail') ) {
            $post_thumbnail     = $request->file('post_thumbnail');
            $filename           = time() . '.' . $post_thumbnail->getClientOriginalExtension();

            Image::make($post_thumbnail)->resize(329.33, 199.33)->save( public_path('uploads/' . $filename ) );

            // Set post-thumbnail url
            $post->post_thumbnail = $filename;
        }

        $post->save();

            return redirect('/') ->with('success', 'Post Created');



    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //list post while we enter through link
        $post= Post::find($id);
        return view('show')-> with('post', $post);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
         $post= Post::find($id);
        return view('edit')-> with('post', $post);
    }


    public function update(Request $request)
    {
            $this -> validate($request,[
            'title' => 'required',
            'content' => 'required'

        ]);
        //create new post
        $post= Post::find($id);
        $post -> title = $request -> input('title');
        $post -> content = $request -> input('content');
        $post -> save();



         // Check if file is present
        if( $request->hasFile('post_thumbnail') ) {
            $post_thumbnail     = $request->file('post_thumbnail');
            $filename           = time() . '.' . $post_thumbnail->getClientOriginalExtension();

            Image::make($post_thumbnail)->resize(329.33, 199.33)->save( public_path('/uploads/' . $filename ) );

            // Set post-thumbnail url
            $post->post_thumbnail = $filename;
        }


            return redirect('/') ->with('success', 'Post Updated');

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post= Post::find($id);
        $post -> delete();
          return redirect('/') ->with('success', 'Post Removed');
    }








}


?>
```

edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
<div class="container2">    
<div class="container">
        <div class="card card-container">
            <!-- <img class="profile-img-card" src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6V8xOA6M7BA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/rzlHcD0KYwo/photo.jpg?sz=120" alt="" /> -->
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">Napiši Vijest</h1>


{!! Form::open(['action' => ['MainController@update', $post -> id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
            {{Form::text('title', $post-> title, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'title'])}}
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('content', 'Content')}}
            {{Form::textarea('content', $post-> content, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'content',  'rows' => 5, 'cols' => 5])}}

        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
               {{  'Select the file to upload.' }}
                 {{    Form::file('image') }}

         </div>  

       <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('post_thumbnail', 'Dodaj Sliku')}}
                {{Form::file('post_thumbnail')}}

         </div>
     <!--Hidden form is used because we want to develope route for edit form whcih is PUT-->
            {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') }}
            {{Form::submit('Prihvati', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
               <a href="{{ route('main') }}" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right: 3px;">Nazad</a>
    {!! Form::close() !!}



        </div><!-- /card-container -->
    </div><!-- /container -->
 </div><!-- /container -->


@endsection
```

routes

```
<?php

Route::resource('path', 'MainController');
//login routes
Route::get('/', 'MainController@successlogin')->name('main');
Route::get('/admin', 'MainController@index');
Route::post('/main/checklogin', 'MainController@checklogin');
Route::get('main/logout', 'MainController@logout');
//posts routes
Route::get('/createPost', 'MainController@create')->name('post.create');
Route::post('/createPost', 'MainController@store')->name('post.create');
Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'MainController@edit')->name('post.edit');
Route::post('/edit/', 'MainController@update')->name('post.update');
Route::get('/delete/{id}', 'MainController@destroy')->name('post.delete');
Route::get('/posts/{id}', 'MainController@show')->name('post.shpw');
```

Comment: Question mark appearing in the URL sounds like your form was using method GET, not POST. Can you check the generated HTML, to verify the form element looks as expected?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ydH21uW you mean something like this ?

Answer (score -1):

I am not using Laravel Form Collective, but In Your Blade I found couple of mistakes  :

1. Since you want to update you have to **add PUT method**
2. You have to **add CSRF token**

Please refer [this documentation link](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html).

Also there is an error in your route. The update function required `$id` to find the specific Post (`$id`).

So change that route as below :

```
Route::post('/edit/{$id}', 'MainController@update')->name('post.update');
```

If there is the same issue after fixing  please inform :)

Comment: Please consider editing your answer using [these formatting tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to make it more readable. Everything seems all jammed together.